# How to get last error (WSAGetLastError)?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, error-handling, pinvoke

How do I call `WSAGetLastError()` from WinAPI so I get the valid text error?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
[DllImport("ws2_32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
static extern Int32 WSAGetLastError();
```

Also, on [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/GetLastError.html) it's said:

> You should never PInvoke to GetLastError.  Call Marshal.GetLastWin32Error instead!

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getlastwin32error.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

`WSAGetLastError` is just a wrapper for the Win32 `GetLastError` function.

If you're doing things with P/Invoke, you can use the `SetLastError` parameter to the `DllImport` attribute. It tells .NET that the imported function will call `SetLastError()`, and that the value should be collected.

If the imported function fails, you can get at the last error with `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()`. Alternatively, you can just `throw new Win32Exception()`, which uses this value automatically.

If you're not doing things with P/Invoke, you're out of luck: there's no guarantee that the last error value will be preserved long enough to make it back through multiple layers of .NET code. In fact, I'll link to Adam Nathan: [never define a PInvoke signature for GetLastError](http://blogs.msdn.com/adam_nathan/archive/2003/04/25/56643.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make very much sense to call that function from managed code. It makes sense in unmanaged code because you know the exact last Win32 function that was called, so you know what function must have set the last error. In managed code, you don't know what functions have been called.

You could probably use P/Invoke to call the function; it just wouldn't do you any good. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score -2):

This is how I saw on the web to put GetLastError into the C# exception mechanismand how to get it back out again...

```
try
{
    // some p/invoke call that is going to fail with a windows error ...
    mHndActivatedDevice = MyNameSpace.Interop.Device.Device.ActivateDevice(
         "Drivers\\BuiltIn\\SomeDriverName", IntPtr.Zero, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
}
catch(System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception exc) // as suggested by John Saunders
{
    // you can get the last error like this:
    int lastError = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    Console.WriteLine("error:" + lastError.ToString());

    // but it is also inside the exception, you can get it like this
    Console.WriteLine(exc.NativeErrorCode.ToString());

    Console.WriteLine(exc.ToString());
}
```

where ActivateDevice is defined thus:

Comment: -1: The code should catch Win32Exception, not Exception. Otherwise, there's a chance of some other exception type being caught, then the case to Win32Exception failing.